# What should be the role of Project Scientist in the team?

Tags: team-management, roles

I have joined one research institute as Project Scientist, but there is no clarification of the job profile here.

What should be the role of Project Scientist in the team? As we work on projects which are client based and also we do research for paper publications in journals, but from a project management perspective what is the exact role? AS a human recourse manager, what is the key responsibility of such a post in the organization? what value it adds to the project by adding such a person to the project?

Also I want to know actually what should be the qualities for the team member to satisfy such a role?

Thannks a lot in advance....

Comment: Can you revise the question to make it a bit clearer how this relates to project management?

Comment: Guessing about what company-specific job descriptions should look like in your organization is outside the scope of PMSE as defined in our [help center](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the title of a Project Scientist, I expect you will be a team member in one or more research projects. Your expected contribution to the project will, most likely, be subject matter expertise to achieve the core objectives of your organization.

Traditionally Scientists have focused on acquiring in-depth expertise in one very narrow area. However, the preference these days is for T-shaped skills.

[T-shaped skills: The vertical bar on the T represents the depth of related skills and expertise in a single field, whereas the horizontal bar is the ability to collaborate across disciplines with experts in other areas and to apply knowledge in areas of expertise other than one's own.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-shaped_skills)

You should also become familiar with how to manage a research project. Here are a couple of starting points:

1. [Introduction to Managing a Research Project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M0JXpjah1K8)
2. [Managing Research the Agile Way](http://technocalifornia.blogspot.com/2011/03/managing-research-agile-way.html)

Answer (score 0):

My first job in the "real world" was as a Project Scientist, so I can empathize with you. Based on my experience they probably want to use you as a "floater", a warm body that can be put onto any project that comes through the door, or alternatively to support any politically powerful principal investigator in your organization. It is like being a consultant, but with twice the headaches, half the pay and a tenth of the authority.

> I have joined one research institute as Project Scientist, but there is no clarification of the job profile here.

Anytime an organization can't provide role clarity it means the organization hasn't got much of a clue around what your role should be. Or if they articulated it nobody would want the job.

> from a project management perspective what is the exact role?

From a PM perspective you are one of many team members, likely more competent than some and less so than others. I would look on you as a generalist and try to keep you on pieces that don't need real speciality knowledge.

> AS a human recourse manager, what is the key responsibility of such a
>   post in the organization? what value it adds to the project by adding
>   such a person to the project?

You probably have the role because there was $$ in the overall organization's budget but not in department/lab budgets. This gives a great deal of flexibility from an HR perspective, and provides a warm body at reasonable cost,